# Importing multiple .xlsx files taken from a network of files

Tags: matlab

I'm a Matlab novice and have been struggling with this particular task for weeks now.

I'm trying to create a nested for loop for uploading all of my data into Matlab. I need the code to go into the file for subject 1, go into the file for the first exercise, upload 3 files (EMG, Kinetic, and kinematic data), then go back and enter the file for the second exercise and upload the data in that file, repeat this for all 5 exercises, and then repeat this whole process for all 12 subjects. I have created code for uploading data from just one file using information I've read off the internet, but to create this programme to get all of the data from all these files has proven to be very difficult.

Below is the code I have currently written:

```
clear all;
Subjects = dir('C:\Users\pricep\Desktop\JuggaData');
Exercise = dir('C:\Users\pricep\Desktop\JuggaData\Subject1');
Trialdata = dir('C:\Users\pricep\Desktop\JuggaData\Subject1\*.xlsx');
subjectnum = numel(Subjects);
exercisenum = numel(Exercise);
datanum = numel(Trialdata);
myData = cell(datanum,1);

for k = 1:subjectnum
    for j = 1:exercisenum
        for i = 1:datanum
           filename = sprintf(Trialdata(i).name);
           myData{k} = importdata(filename);
        end
    end   
end
```

No error message appears, but no data appears either.

As you can tell I'm a complete novice so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that `subjectnum`, `exercisenum` and `datanum` are above zero, probably one of the files is zero causing nothing to happen. Besides this, there are other issues:

- exercisenum is constant, which assumes that every subject has the same amount of exercises. Might be wrong.
- dir returns the file names `..` (parent directory) and `.` (current directory) as well. You don't filter these.
- `importdata` is called with a relative file path, which is not possible.
- `myData = cell(datanum,1);` allocates not enough space, assuming there is more than one subject and exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Daniel. Would you recommend just reading the data through xlsread, instead of using importdata? I plan to extend the loop to include code for filtering and saving to another directory.

Comment: Also, how should I extend myData? is it not big enough because I'm uploading it as a cell array or is it just the dimensions I'm stating which isn't big enough?